# Where is my datetime?

Tags: c#, reference, xunit

So I'm trying out TDD (I'm using xunit, if that makes any difference) and I have a test file:

```
public class GatheringModuleTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void GathererGathersSourceCommunications()
    {
        GatheringClass thing = new GatheringClass(sourceStreamReader, targetStreamReader, ref sourceCommunications, ref targetCommunications);

        thing.Process(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        Assert.True(sourceCommunications.Any());
    }
}

public class GatheringClass 
{
    private StreamReader sourceStreamReader;
    private StreamReader targetStreamReader;
    private List<Communication> sourceCommunications;
    private List<Communication> targetCommunications;

    public GatheringClass(StreamReader sourceStreamReader, StreamReader targetStreamReader, 
    ref List<Communication> sourceCommunications, ref List<Communication> targetCommunications)
    {
        this.sourceStreamReader = sourceStreamReader;
        this.targetStreamReader = targetStreamReader;
        this.sourceCommunications = sourceCommunications;
        this.targetCommunications = targetCommunications;
    }

    public void Process(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var dt = new DateTime();
        var line = sourceStreamReader.ReadLine();

        var lineArray = line.Split('\0');
        var communication = new MatchCommunication();
        communication.PublishedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are a couple of classes here. I'm also referencing an external library with a "Communication" object. Looking at the "Process" method, you can see that I have a dummy DateTime that the compiler has no issue with. However, the communication object has a DateTime field "PublishedDate" which is generating squiggles:

```
The type 'DateTime' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: This class won't compile. There's a missing `;` at the last line of code.

Comment: Did you delete a reference to the assembly your error message is complaining about?

Comment: I don't see the word "Object" anywhere in the code you've posted. Can you try again with the relevant code?

Comment: @DigiFriend fixed it, but it was squaking at me before I even built it. I haven't deleted any references.

Comment: @itsme86 just edited the error. exactly the same issue, though.

Comment: Did you change the target framework or something? At any rate, add the reference it's telling you to add and it should work.

Comment: Look at your references... `mscorlib` is where a lot of the primitive types live - could be that you are mixing libraries from different versions.

Comment: Maybe it's my unfamiliarity with xunit, but I don't see references. I see dependencies, but I don't see anyway to add a reference to mscorlib. also, the DateTime object works just fine outside of this spot. The Communication model likes in another project in the solution, if that sheds any light.

Comment: Do you see this in Visual Studio? What version do you use? What is the project (inside Solution Explorer in VS), and if you check the project's properties, what is "Target framework", "Output type", etc.? Normally, you cannot add a reference to the `mscorlib` assembly explicitly from the Solution Explorer; it will give you the message _A reference to 'mscorlib' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system._ So it seems strange it asks for that assembly. It could be a .NET version targeted issue.

Comment: Maybe the type `MatchCommunication` is defined in a project/assembly that targets a newer version of .NET compared to what you target? Are you trying to create a .NET 3.5 project that references a project that uses .NET 4.0 or later?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are including a library that has defined an alternative version of the class `DateTime`.

When you say

```
var dt = new DateTime()
```

You are perhaps instantiating the new DateTime class. You could step into the relevant code in a debugger to test this.

Howvever when you say

```
communication.PublishedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Perhaps you are referencing the standard DateTime.Now function rather than the Datetime provided.

It's just a guess, but it would explain the difference.